# Pointers in boost::intrusive::splay_set

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I'm currently trying to learn how to use boost library and I've stumbled upon a problem with boost::intrusive::splay_set (or splaytree in that matter).

Let's assume I want to have splay tree that keeps pointers to Category class (so Category*). I'm trying to write following

```
splay_set<Category*, compare<std::greater<Category*>>> CategoriesSplay
```

Sadly, it doesn't work. I won't write errors it's generating since it's exceeding 100 and Visual Studio is terminating compilation process.

Then I tried to change class that my Category class should be extending to

```
class Category : public splay_set_base_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>, Category*>
```

Again, no luck here. changing Category* in 2nd code to void_pointer(Category) doesn't work either. Sadly boost documentation is no help in adding pointers to intrusive splay sets.

Have anyone got some solution to my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the errors? (At least the first few.)

Comment: It actually depends on how I define the extending class template. If it's defined as above my errors are: `error C2825: 'Next': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'` `error C2903: 'pack' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template`But if it's left withouth defining pointer errors are `error C2825: 'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'` `error C2039: 'default_splay_set_hook' : is not a member of '`global namespace''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, you shouldn't store a pointer to your object, you should store the actual object. So your declaration should look like this:

```
splay_set<Category, compare<std::greater<Category>>> CategoriesSplay
```

Second, you need to implement the data members in your class that the container needs to do its work. The easiest way is to just inherit from the base "hook" class, like so:

```
class Category : public splay_set_base_hook<> {
...
```

Remember: the intrusive containers do not manage the memory of their contained objects the way the STL containers do. You need to allocate your object *before* you insert it into the container and make sure you delete it when you remove it.